# What (if anything) should be done on frontend to be able to see UTM tracking data in Google Ads?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, utm

As a frontend developer I've been tasked with the following. The customer is using Google Ads to get traffic to their website A. They can successfully track campaigns in their Google Ads dashboard. Now they want to be able to do the same for website B, which is on the same domain. And they ask me to do it.

**Do I need to do anything as frontend developer to make customer able to track UTM campaigns on website B? E.g. do I need to send Google Analytics events, do need to configure something on frontend side?**

I found it very hard to find any info on how it actually works (there is a ton of very basic articles on what UTM parameters are, how to generate them and rubbish like that, but nothing about how Google knows when someone landed on a URL with UTM parameters). If anything, I am under impression that it should just work out of the box.